# Change color of a texture in a specific matrix location

Tags: c#, xna, visual-studio

I have following bool matrix:

```
bool[,] centerPiece = new bool[,] { { false, true, false }, { true, true, true }, { false, true, false } };
```

Using a method, I put a texture down every time the boolean hits true. Is there a way for me to select an individual texture in the matrix and change it's color independently, without changing the others in the same matrix?

I'm aware I have to use the `Color` method to change the color,
and that to select a specific point in my matrix the syntax is along the lines of `centerPiece[1,1]`, but the rest baffles me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a boolean array, you are going to want to consider creating a Tile class that will deal with your drawable entity that you see on your screen.

```
public class Tile { 

    public Color Color;

    void Update() {
       //update logic
    }  

    void Draw() { 
       //render
       //spriteBatch.Draw(use your Color);
    }
}
```

Then have a Tile based array:

```
Tile[,] Tiles = new Tile[Width, Height];

// init your tiles
for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++) {
        Tile tile = new Tile();
        tile.Color = Color.Red;
        Tiles[x,y] = tile;
    }
}
```

Then you can just change a tile color by indexing it like:

```
Tiles[0, 1].Color = Color.Blue;
```

Comment: I've tried messing around with something along the lines of your post. It doesn't seem like you can add .Color to either textures or classes.

Comment: You can definitely add a Color property to a custom class.  In fact, I just showed you an example in the code above.

Comment: My bad, initialized my class wrong :-)